# Install with php 5.5.16 laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I try to install Laravel 4.2, i have ubuntu 14.04 and php 5.5.16 with apache2.4.10. The install works..., but i have a message with composer install:

```
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
```

When i change a permission to storage (chmod 777 -R app/storage) directory and i put debug at true into config file app.php, the command php artisan optimize works whell.

Do you think, i have something wrong with my PHP configuration or permission directory ?

Tony, thank

Comment: Could you post the command you are executing and the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely its permissions. Check to make sure your www-data has the right permissions